# Windows Explorer Shortcut to go to next sibling folder?

Tags: windows-10

I am searching for a key shortcut in Windows 10 that allows me to navigate from folder A to folder B from inside folder A:

```
- Top Folder
-- A (I am here)
-- B
```

Shortcut, then:

```
- Top Folder
-- A 
-- B (now I am here)
```

Could not find information about a native shortcut for this.

PS: An AHK script would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with this great Autohotkey script:

```
; navigate to next sibling folder from Windows Explorer
#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass")
^PgUp::
^PgDn:: NavigateToSiblingDir( InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "Up") )

NavigateToSiblingDir(UpDown)  {
   oShell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
   WinGet, hWnd,, A
   for oWin in oShell.Windows  {
      if (hWnd = oWin.hwnd)  {
         oFolder := oWin.Document.Folder
         startDirPath  := oFolder.Self.Path
         parentDirPath := oFolder.ParentFolder.Self.Path
         break
      }
   }

   for item in oShell.Namespace(parentDirPath).Items  {
      if !item.IsFolder
         continue
      if (found && nextSiblingPath := item.Path)
         break
      if (item.Path = startDirPath && found := true)
         prevSiblingPath := prev
      prev := item.Path
   }

   if (UpDown && prevSiblingPath)
      oWin.Navigate(prevSiblingPath)
   if (!UpDown && nextSiblingPath)
      oWin.Navigate(nextSiblingPath)
}
```

Github: [explorer-navigate-sibling-folder.ahk](https://github.com/q2apro/ahk-snippets/blob/master/explorer-navigate-sibling-folder.ahk)

My heartly gratitude and credits go to [teadrinker & jeeswg (AHK)](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=40200).